# JSON no implicit conversion of String into Integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm grabbing a JSON hash from my server and trying to read it in my ruby script.  It seems to be returning the wrong value though, unless I'm just loosing my mind:

I'm calling this from a function:

```
def get_functions(serial_number)
  response = HTTParty.get("#{get_host_url}/v1/devices/#{serial_number}.json")
  data = response['scan_option']
  return data
end
```

Here is the returned JSON:

```
{"can_scan"=>true, "can_brute_ssh"=>false, "can_brute_telnet"=>false, "can_brute_voip"=>false, "can_brute_smtp"=>false, "can_brute_pop3"=>false, "can_google_crawl"=>false, "can_scan_external_ip"=>false, "scan_ip_list"=>["10.10.10.1"], "exclude_ip_list"=>[]}
```

Which is then read into the following code:

```
data.each do |d|
  @can_scan = d['can_scan']
  # ....
end
```

However this is throwing an error:

> no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Comment: Why on earth would you expect that code to work? The JSON in your question is an object/hash not an array that can be iterated through.  What you want is `data["scan_option"].try(:[], "can_scan")`.

Comment: Sorry, copied it from Postman... updated the code with the actual JSON pulled from the console.

Comment: Thats still a hash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{foo: :bar}.each do |d|
  p d
  d['meow']
end
  # => [:foo, :bar]
  #! TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

`Hash#each` yields a two element array (`[key, value]`). You then try to index that array with `d["can_scan"]`, which fails as arrays can only be indexed with integers.

---

Instead, directly access the value - `data['can_scan']`.

Answer (score 1):

I you mean that `data` in your third snippet (where you call `data.each`) is the hash mentioned just above it, indeed that would be troublesome. Calling `each` on a hash will itterate over its key, value pairs, giving you an array in the block var `d` of the `data.each` (with a `[key, value]` pair in it).

You might just want to call `data['can_scan']`.

Note that the `return` at the end of your method defenition is not needed in Ruby. You can just do:

`def get_functions(serial_number)
  response = HTTParty.get("#{get_host_url}/v1/devices/#{serial_number}.json")
  response["scan_option"]
end`

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation.